# Helm - comma-separated list of dynamic strings

Tags: kubernetes, yaml, kubernetes-helm, go-templates

Is it possible, within a [helm](/questions/tagged/helm) chart to create a single string which is a comma-separated representation (similar to using the `",".join()` command in Python) of strings with a common prefix and a variable suffix?

For example, I have a CLI application that requires an argument like so via the `extraArgs` parameter in a [kubernetes](/questions/tagged/kubernetes) pod definition:

```
extraArgs: >-
  -M {{ $.Values.global.hostname }}/100
```

I now have to modify this value to be over a range (i.e. from `{{$.Values.global.minval}}` to `{{$.Values.global.maxval}}`, inclusive). So, for a `minval=100` and `maxval=105`, my chart needs to now become (note the lack of a trailing comma, and no spaces other than the space after `-M`):

```
extraArgs: >-
  -M {{ $.Values.global.hostname }}/100,{{ $.Values.global.hostname }}/101,{{ $.Values.global.hostname }}/102,{{ $.Values.global.hostname }}/103,{{ $.Values.global.hostname }}/104,{{ $.Values.global.hostname }}/105
```

Is there some way I can execute this in a range/loop in my chart? I have several instances of this chart that will use different min/max values, and I'd like to automate this tedious task as much as I can (additionally, I **do not** have access to the app's source, so I can't change the CLI interface to the application).

In Python, I could accomplish this roughly by:

```
minval = 100
minval = 105
s = "-M "
L = []
for i in range(minval, maxval+1):
    L.append("{{{{ $.Values.global.hostname }}}}/{}".format(i))
s = s + ",".join(L)
# print(s)
```

I'm not sure where to begin doing this in a Helm template beyond starting with the `range()` function.

Comment: You could use [`range untilstep`](https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/1055) for part of this, and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47668793/helm-generate-comma-separated-list) to generate the comma separated list. Not sure where you'll dump your intermediate list so it doesn't end up needlessly in the final chart.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Helm: generate comma separated list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47668793/helm-generate-comma-separated-list)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Helm includes the [sprig library](https://masterminds.github.io/sprig) of template functions which contains [`untilStep`](https://masterminds.github.io/sprig/integer_slice.html) and [`join`](https://masterminds.github.io/sprig/string_slice.html).

There is no concept of a [`map` or `each` operator in sprig](https://github.com/Masterminds/sprig/issues/91) yet so you can construct the list in a `range` loop to be joined later ([from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59173597/1318694))

```
{{- $minval :=  int .Values.minval -}}
{{- $maxval :=  int .Values.maxval | add1 | int -}}
{{- $args := list -}}
{{- range untilStep $minval $maxval 1 -}}
{{-   $args = printf "%s/%d" $hostname . | append $args -}}
{{- end }}
extraArgs: '-M {{ $args | join "," }}'
```

Comment: Beautiful! Thank you!

Comment: Very nice implementation!