# Idiomatic way of mapping over list with go templates/helm

Tags: kubernetes-helm, go-templates

So let's assume I have the following `values.yaml`:

```yaml
services:
  - MyService1
  - MyService2
  - MyService3
```

I want to have a way to render the following:

```yaml
someStringField: "myservice1_cert,myservice2_cert,myservice3_cert"
```

Comment: Are you looking for [Helm: generate comma separated list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47668793/helm-generate-comma-separated-list)?

Answer (score 0):

```yaml
  {{- $res := list }}
  {{- range .Values.services }}
  {{- $res = append $res (printf "%s_cert" (lower .)) }}
  {{- end }}
  someStringField: {{ join "," $res }}
```