# helm range loop over values array onliner to get comma separated values list

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I am new to helm chart , attempting to form my connection string to connect to mongodb cluster, here is my Values.yaml file:

```
mongos:
  - mongos1
  - mongos2
```

Here is my Template.yaml:

```
 uri: {{ "mongodb://" -}} {{ range $value := .Values.mongos }} {{-  printf "%s:27017" $value  -}} {{- end }}
```

But cannot figure out how to add the commas , here is current result:

```
  uri: mongodb://mongos1:27017mongos2:27017
```

It needs to look as follow:

```
  uri: "mongodb://mongos1:27017,mongos2:27017/?authSource=admin"
```

[Playground](https://helm-playground.com/#t=LQhQFcCcEsC4AIDej4CIC2B7Adgc0wCYBGsA9KavMAL7VIqQCGeApvACQBujANuG7AC88AHQA1XvwDOIrHkxT4tesHjwADjGwAXAGZoApFNgAmAOwAGAIxnKXSWyrLkqltgJLqoUEA&v=LQhQFsHsDsHNIM4C5QAJXFVOiCMaMsZ4EAmAzbEgZjVCA)

Please, advice how to add the commas between the host:port so it get correct list if I add arbitrary number of mongos in the values.yaml in the future?

Comment: Does [Helm: generate comma separated list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47668793/helm-generate-comma-separated-list?rq=1) answer your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When iterating through the hosts, you can also get access to the index, and use this to conditionally prepend a comma

```
uri: {{ "mongodb://" -}} {{ range $i, $value := .Values.mongos }} {{- if $i -}},{{- end }} {{-  printf "%s:27017" $value  -}} {{- end }}
```

Another option is to use the `join` function as David suggested, but to pre-create a temporary list holding the hostname+ports

```
{{ $hostsAndPorts := list }}
{{ range .Values.mongos }}
  {{ $hostAndPort := printf "%s:27017" . }}
  {{ $hostsAndPorts = append $hostAndPort }}
{{ end }}

...


uri: {{ "mongodb://" }}{{ $hostsAndPorts | join "," }}{{ "/?authSource=admin" }}
```

Answer (score 1):

I might write a helper template that takes in the list of host names, appends a port number and a comma to each, and returns the resulting string.  So long as there is at least one host name, this string is guaranteed to end with an unwanted comma, which is important.

```
{{- define "mongo.hosts" -}}
{{- range . -}}
{{ . }}:27017,
{{- end -}}
{{- end -}}
```

Now you can use Helm-specific `include` to evaluate that template, capturing the result in a string, and remove the trailing comma.

```yaml
url: mongodb://{{ include "mongo.hosts" .Values.mongos | trimSuffix "," }}
```

The Sprig support library includes a [`join`](https://masterminds.github.io/sprig/string_slice.html) function, and this is also present in Helm, so in principle you can `join "," $hostsAndPorts`.  But you need to get a list of strings as its input, and it's a little bit tricky to transform one list of strings to another in the template language.

Comment: Nice one. A possible improvement: use `$i, $val := range .` and prepend the comma conditionally (`{{ if $i }},{{end}}{{ . }}:27017`), would remove the need for `trimSuffix`

Comment: Thanks alot! This one is maybe more professional , but I decided to use the one onliner provided by @LudovicC below ...

Answer (score 0):

Adding also the one chatGPT provided:

```
  {{- define "mongodbConnection" -}} {{- $first := true -}} {{- range . -}} {{- if not $first }},{{ end }}{{ . }}:27017{{- $first = false -}} {{- end -}}{{- end -}}
  uri: {{ printf "mongodb://%s/?authSource=admin" (include "mongodbConnection" .Values.mongos) }}
```